# Formulas are not updating in Excel, Java Apache API

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-2013

I have two excel documents excel1.**xls** and excel2.**xlsm**. Where I read the data from excel1 and write it to excel2 using Apache API. In excel2 file, some cells have the formulas to auto update.

Problem: When the excel2 file is last opened/saved with Microsoft Excel 2007, everything works fine. But, when its last opened/saved with 2013 version, the auto update cell doesn't work anymore. All the computers at work are now moved to Office 2013, So I can't use Excel 2007 anymore.

I have already checked/set the setting Formulas - > Calculations Options -> Automatic in Excel

I also tried to use `evaluateFormulaCell()` and `evaluateAllFormulaCells()`methods in the program, doesn't update anything.

I am not sure, whether the excel has some kind of security, which is stopping to auto update?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with `poi 3.13` even without evaluation. I'd recommend check your macros. Also please provide some examples (code, source file) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The formula's are auto update, so macro's are not involved in it. I do have macros in that file for other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
```

This method worked for me, before I only used to call this method at the end, but now I called it every time I set a single cell and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to re-save the excel files in 2007 format. This could solve it.